# How to scrape URLs from a web page using the rvest package in R?

Tags: css, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape URLs from a web page, and I'm using SelectorGadget to identify the correct CSS or XPath selection:

[image]

Here's my R code:

```
library(rvest)

baseUrl <- 'http://hibid.com/auctions/current/lots/?group=23&ipp=10'

t <- baseUrl %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(css = '.lot-link') %>%
  html_text()
```

I'm expecting this to return the URL in the highlighted link, but it only returns a vector of tab and newline characters.  Running the code with the suggested XPath

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "lot-link", " " ))]
```

yields the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This page is dynamically created, rvest is not the tool to use.  RSelenium might be the package to use.

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks for the info.  Would you know how to parse this type of content using RSelenium?  Specifically, is it just a question of choosing the appropriate value type when applying the findElement method?